# PostgreSQL admin account

Tags: postgresql

After doing an initial installation and setup of PostgreSQL, what is considered "best practice" when it comes to an admin account?
You have the postgres user, of course. Do people set a password on this account and use that for administration purposes both locally and remotely trough tools such as pgadmin?
Or do people create a dedicated account for administration purposes, and only use Postgres locally?

Comment: More appropriate for [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Yes, in retrospect I agree. But not allowed to post there for 40 minutes

Comment: Restrain that urge to post. **Search first.** This issue has been covered many times on both sites.

Comment: I actually did a search, but found nothing related to this. If you have any examples that can help be me, I would be grateful.

Comment: definetely create a dedicated one